# My Schema mapping function does not matches the regex while consuming from Kafka pipeline although regex looks fine

Tags: regex, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a requirement where I need to first match the regex in the log and if it matches then do the regex extract, but somehow the regex is not working in the Kafka pipeline while the regex works completely fine when tested on any online regex tester platform.

Lets say I have input topic : topic1 and output topic : topic2
topic1 contains all the log entries which has some sort of error.

I have created one transformation pipeline with a schema using mapping as :

```
"mapping.config":"fields = [ { condition { function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = [ "message", "Error \d{4}"] }, mapping { "timestamp" = "timestamp", "host" = "host", "service" = "service",  "message.errorcode" ={ function = "REGEX_EXTRACT", args = ["message", "Error (\d{4})", 1]}]
```

the error in the log looks like (in toipc1):

```
"message": {"string": "<userId xmlns=\"\">xxxxxxxxx</userId><command type=\"Error\" echo=\"test\" xsi:type=\"c:ErrorResponse\" xmlns:c=\"C\" xmlns=\"\"><summary>[Error 4007] Invalid login ID: xxxxxx</summary><summaryEnglish>[Error 4007] Invalid login ID: xxxxx</summaryEnglish></command>"}
```

I need to read the value inside square bracket[]
so that I get in the output topic topic2 something like
"message": {"errorcode": "4007"}

Can anyone please help me out here

Thanks in advance .

What regex I have tried yet the log entries are skipped assuming it is not matching the regular expression.

```
{ function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = [ "message", "Error .+?\]"  ] { function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = ["message", "Error\s\d+"] } { function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = [ "message", "summary>\[Error(.+?)\]"] } { function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = [ "message", "Error (\d{4})"] } { function = "MATCHES_REGEX", args = [ "message", "Error \d{4}"] }
```

Comment: What connector are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue is fixed after using a Java compatible regex:

I am using `summary>.{1}Error.{1}(.{4})` instead of `summary>\[Error(.+?)\]` and it worked. I validated it using https://regex101.com/